# connect k8s to an database in same private cloud infrastructure but in different network

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cloud

I'm looking for an example how to connect my k8s in my (oracle) cloud with an database in the same cloud infrastructure but in another VCN and not to walk over the internet.
Any useful links?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need a local VCN peering between these two VCNs:
   https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/localVCNpeering.htm
2. Once you have it make sure security group (firewall rule) of DB instance is adjusted: DB instance allows incoming connections to DB port from the kubernetes node security group
   https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/networksecuritygroups.htm

Comment: Thank you for the links! So is nothing special to K8s but only a network configuration thing?

Comment: Yeah, just make sure you know the k8s node sec group. Usually when a cloud provider offers k8s they just wrap it in own hypervisor instances, so basically using a different `exec` command inside but it's exactly the same from the outside.